# Foreign key C# one to many not setting entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to update a text status and foreign keyed status id.

```
public class Model : DbModelBuilder
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; } //relationship mappings

    public virtual Statuses StatusId { get; set; }
}

public class Statuses
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required] public string StatusName { get; set; }
}

public void updateStatus(String status, int statusId = 0)
{
    using (Context ctx = new Context())
    {
        if (statusId != 0)
        {
            if (ctx.Statuses.Any(ts => ts.id == statusId))
            {
                model.StatusId = ctx.Statuses.Find(statusId);
            }
        }
        model.Status = status;
        ctx.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The text status sets correctly, but the foreign key status is not updated.

I've got a similar function in the another class when updating the entire model and it works without any issues.

I'm able to see that the model updates by logging the information. However if I log ctx.model.statusId after ctx.savechanges() the statusId isn't updated.

Comment: Where is your model variable declared? `model.StatusId = ctx.Statuses.Find(statusId);`  -- that should error out since Find returns your entity, not the Id.

Comment: I'm confused by that assignment `model.StatusId = ctx.Statuses.Find(statusId);`... do you really have a member called `StatusId` *as well as* a member called `Status`? I assume you've mis-typed it and it should be assigning to `model.Status` - in which case it'll be overwritten by the later assignment to the same member?

Comment: The foreign keyed status is used to track the model through the application where as the text status is used to provide the user with step by step information as the model is processing.

Comment: Please show the class definition for your 'model' class.

Comment: public class Model : DbModelBuilder
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        //relationship mappings
        public virtual Statuses StatusId { get; set; }
}

Comment: public class Statuses
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I've added these definitions to the question. Wow, you have confusing entity / property names! :-)

Comment: I've identified the issue. I was unable to use the new context to update an existing instance of the model. I had to grab a new instance within the current context.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are 3 possible execution paths here:

1. The `statusId` parameter is zero, and the code in the `if` block is not executed.
2. The `statusId` parameter is non-zero, but does not match the ID of any existing `Statuses` entry in the database (so the `Any()` test fails and the assignment to `model.StatusId` is not done).
3. The `statusId` parameter is non-zero and it *does* match the ID of an existing `Statuses` entry (so the `Any()` test succeeds, and the assignment to `model.StatusId` *is* done).

In case #1 I would *not* expect the `model.StatusId` field to be updated by `SaveChanges`, because although you've set the `string` property `Status`, there's nothing to link that to a `Statuses` entity or cause EF to think they're related.

Same for case #2 since no additional assignments are made.

For case #3, you've set the `StatusId` property *before* calling `SaveChanges`, so it should still be set *after* `SaveChanges`.

So... I'm not sure which case you think is failing, or why you think the `StatusId` value would be updated?

Comment: Case #3 is failing to save the changes to the foreign key. I'm able to log that I've reached the statusId set statement and that the model is updated but the changes are never committing to the database.
The text status is updating.